# SVG filters feDisplacementMap same inputs, different result

Tags: svg, filter

I have a filtered image rendering as expected [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-8nk1wx?file=index.html).

- feImage = imageA
- img element = imageB
- in = feImage
- in2 = SourceGraphic

However, if I swap the images around but maintain the same input values [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-aqg71t?file=index.html):

- feImage = imageB
- img element = imageA
- in = SourceGraphic
- in2 = feImage

The result is different. This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feDisplacementMapElement)

> The ‘color-interpolation-filters’ property only applies to the ‘in2’ source image and does not apply to the ‘in’ source image. The ‘in’ source image must remain in its current color space.

So in2 has to be converted to the linearRGB colour space (since that's the default value for color-interpolation-filters), while the in input is RGB because images are RGB by definition. Some UAs may not be doing this properly because it certainly looks the same in Firefox.

Comment: I'm assuming that's what the feColorMatrix is doing in this example - https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ConformedText/. Copying these elements into a sandbox doesn't render the same result - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-f3ds6m?file=index.html. I'm stumped as to why.

Comment: Locally I was able to get this code to work. If I made a request to get the image used as the map, it doesn't work. If the image is stored locally however, it works.